# element raise TimeoutException

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests, webdriverwait

I have problem with test in selenium, I tried to use other wait method and nothing works.

html

```
<span class="MuiTypography-root MuiListItemText-primary MuiTypography-body1">Sign Out</span>
```

log_out.py

```
imports


    @when('I click on sign out button')
    def step_impl(context):
        wait = WebDriverWait(context.browser, 20)
        #navbar_right_content = context.browser.find_element_by_css_selector("div[class^='navbar-user-profile-menu']")
        navbar_right_content = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"div[class^='menu']")))
        navbar_right_content.click()
        sign_out = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH,'//span*[contains(text(), "Sign Out")]')))
        sign_out.click()
```

> Error

```
>       Traceback (most recent call last):
>         File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/support/wait.py",
> line 80, in until
>           raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
>       selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:
```

Comment: Is this `*` inside `//span*[contains(text(), "Sign Out")]` intentional?

Comment: Yes, and without this error is the same.

Comment: Does changing `visibility_of_element_located` to `presence_of_element_located` change the error?

Comment: I tried also with 'clickable', still the same.

Comment: I removed watir because watir related to ruby selenium binding.

Comment: Did you check for the presence of iframes before this element?

Comment: Nope, Could you tell me more details?